# Some .NET manifest thing appears in a freshly installed application, why?

Tags: .net

After I installed a program (easyphp), in some EXE files the following string appears:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>PAPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDING
```

and I cant use it. What to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest indicates to the Windows Dll loader which version of the Visual C runtime it should load. This mechanism allows multiple versions of Dlls to be installed "side-by-side" and for programs to specify which version of a Dll they depend on.

This manifest also defines some security privileges.

The manifest is designed to be used by the operating system, not you.

Comment: ok I found it... I just had to install .NET, and now that exe program doesnt trigger error